# Modifying GET parameter on PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I'm very newbie to this, so let me explain the issue:

I have a cashback script, the retailer title is stored in the database, my links looking like that:

example.com/view_retailer.php?id=232

I want to change that to /view_retailer?title=retailer-title

I can't figure why its not working, I have on my DB the columns retailer_id, title and retailer_url. Retailer_url is empty.

```
if (!function_exists('GetRetailerLink')) {
    function GetRetailerLink($retailer_id, $retailer_title = "") {
        $retailer_id = (int)$retailer_id;

        $retailer_link = SITE_URL."view_retailer.php?id=".$retailer_id;
        return $retailer_link;
```

In php page view_retailer:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    {
        $retailer_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    }
    else
    {       
        header ("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
```

I played already around with the code below but this is not working -> shop not found.

```
if (!function_exists('GetRetailerLink')) {
    function GetRetailerLink($retailer_id, $retailer_title = "") {
        $retailer_id = (int)$retailer_id;

        $retailer_link = SITE_URL."view_retailer.php?title=".$retailer_title;
        return $retailer_link;
```

and

```
if (isset($_GET['title']) && is_numeric($_GET['title']))
                {
                    $retailer_title = (int)$_GET['title'];
                }
                else
                {       
                    header ("Location: index.php");
                    exit();
                }
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for helping me!

---

Thank you for the proposed solutions

I tried it now with

```
if (!function_exists('GetRetailerLink')) {
    function GetRetailerLink($retailer_id, $retailer_title = "") {
        $retailer_id = (int)$retailer_id;

        $retailer_link = SITE_URL."view_retailer.php?title=".$retailer_title;
        return $retailer_link;
```

and

```
if (isset($_GET['title']) && is_string($_GET['title']))
{
    $retailer_title = (string)$_GET['title'];
}
else
{       
    header ("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

also tried it with

```
if (isset($_GET['title']))
            {
                $retailer_title = (int)$_GET['title'];
            }
            else
            {       
                header ("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem either -> Shop not found.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove `is_numeric($_GET['title'])` in your code.

`is_numeric($_GET['title'])` will check if the variable is a number or a numeric string.

Comment: Hi, I have removed this but this isn't working. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Hi, try below.
if (isset($_GET['title']))
            {
                $retailer_title = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            }
            else
            {       
                header ("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            }

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try removing is_numeric? Since title is a character string, that will return false always.

```
if (isset($_GET['title']))
            {
                $retailer_title = $_GET['title'];
            }
            else
            {       
                header ("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but that don't solve the issue.